Movie with black and white soldiers in the brig
I watched this movie in high school so the movie is at least 25 yrs old.  Not sure how long the movie is but we watched it over several class periods.  The movie had Charlie Sheen, Martin Sheen, and Lawrence Fishburne in it.
There were a bunch of black soldiers who were in the brig for various crimes.  Martin Sheen played the racist army warden of the brig.  Fishburne played the leader of the soldiers in the brig.  Charlie Sheen played some soldier who got thrown into the brig, being the only white soldier in the brig.
I think the basic premise of the movie was race relations and how the soldiers eventually accepted and trusted C. Sheen.  Something happened that made them kind of turn their back on him but in the end of the movie, they accept him as their own again.

Er, no offense, but why not just Google the actors' names? This is Cadence from 1990. But +1 anyway, for a detailed ID question.

@Walt ... is correct on both accounts.

OK, I'll put it up, if no one else is game.

You're looking for Cadence from 1990:

PFC Franklin Bean (Charlie Sheen) gets drunk and goes AWOL upon the death of his father. As punishment, he is thrown into a stockade populated entirely by black inmates. But instead of giving into racism, Bean joins forces with his fellow inmates and rises up against the bigoted prison warden, MSgt. Otis McKinney (Martin Sheen).

Here's the trailer:



